# Emplacement de l'adjectif « efficaces. »

Tags: expressions, adjectifs, ordre-des-mots

> Algorithmes d'allocations de ressources efficaces.
>
> Algorithmes de sélections efficaces.

L'adjectif « efficaces » est utilisé pour décrire les algorithmes.

Dans ces deux expressions, est-ce que l'emplacement de l'adjectif « efficaces » est bon ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pour éviter toute confusion, il vaut mieux écrire : "Algorithmes efficaces d'allocations de ressources".
"Algorithme" étant de genre masculin, "ressource" étant féminin, il existe une autre possibilité : trouver un synonyme d'efficace qui soit plus explicite... "Algorithmes d'allocations de ressources performants." (Ici, "performants" au masculin pluriel ne peut se rapporter qu'à "algorithmes".)

Answer (score 2):

Cela me semble correct, mais pour lever toute ambiguïté, j'aurais tendance à placer l'adjectif juste après le mot :

> Algorithmes efficaces d'allocations de ressources.
>
> Algorithmes efficaces de sélections.